# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages reponse

Tags: composer

During installing Magento using Composer i get:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.5].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5 requires ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
Problem 2
- magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.7.0, ..., 3.11.1] require ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
- Root composer.json requires magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework ^3.7 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.7.0, ..., 3.11.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-bz2.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
- /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-intl --ignore-platform-req=ext-intl` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Below I'm sending how my php --ini looks like:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/8.1/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-bz2.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini

Could I ask you for any advice?

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are my results:

/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini:;extension=intl
/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini:;extension=intl
/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini:;extension=intl
/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini:;extension=intl
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/intl.ini:extension=intl.so
/etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini:;extension=intl
/etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini:;extension=intl

So what exactly should i remove and where?

Answer (score 0):

Magento requires PHP **intl** extension, it is missing from your system.

1. Check if your PHP installed **intl** extension or not by running the command `grep -r extension=intl /etc`.

- If you see any result like `/etc/php.d/20-intl.ini:;extension=intl`, open `/etc/php.d/20-intl.ini` file to remove the semicolon before `extension=intl`.
- If you see any result like `/etc/php-zts.d/20-intl.ini:;extension=intl`, open `/etc/php-zts.d/20-intl.ini` file to remove the semicolon before `extension=intl`.

Then restart your Web server.
open /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini

2. If you don't see results like above, that indicates you didn't install **intl** extensions yet, you can install it by running the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install php8.1-intl
```

Comment: If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as **accepted**. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer.

Comment: These are my results:

/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini:;extension=intl
/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini:;extension=intl
/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini:;extension=intl
/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini:;extension=intl
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/intl.ini:extension=intl.so
/etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini:;extension=intl
/etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini:;extension=intl

So what exactly should i remove and where?

Comment: Open `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini` file, remove the semicolon from `;extension=intl`, then restart apache.

Comment: After removing semicolon from ;extension=intl in /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini, when I typed grep -r extension=intl /et I only gained another result: /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini.save:;extension=intl

Maybe that's because I didn't restart appache, but for /etc/init.d/apache2 restart I get:


Restarting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!

Comment: You getting that error because you have some syntax error in /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini when you edit that file. Check that file again to make sure everything has the correct syntax. Did you edit other files beside /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini? If so, you should check these files to make sure everything has the correct syntax.

Comment: If the problem is caused by not restarting appache, then for /etc/init.d/apache2 restart I get:


Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!

Comment: Only this one file and only by removing this on symbol

Comment: Please run this command to detect which file caused the new error: `sudo journalctl | tail`

Comment: Then edit your question to add the file content of that file in the result, I'll take a look.

Comment: ;extension=gmp
extension=intl
;extension=imap

But now I probably gained new file in /etc/php/8.1/cli/ named php.ini.save. Is that correct?

But I mark, I still didn't restart appache. For /etc/init.d/apache2 restart I get: Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. failed!

Comment: Try to move `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini.save` to somewhere like `/etc/php` or `/home/` then restart apache

Comment: And you also need to remove the semicolon from `;extension=intl` from this file too: `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini`. In total, you need to edit 2 files: `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: Ok, now I edited /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini too. One change in second file. After changes:

;extension=gmp
extension=intl
;extension=imap

Interestingly, in /etc/php/8.1/apache2/ file named php.ini.save didn't appear.

I moved php.ini.save from /etc/php/8.1/cli/ to /etc/php (maybe should I delete this file?).

Now, for /etc/init.d/apache2 restart i still get

Restarting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!

Comment: You can delete `php.ini.save` once your apache is able to restart and works as expected. Please run this command to detect which file caused the new error: `sudo journalctl | tail`

Comment: Invalid user bitrix from
pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure;
Failed password for invalid user bitrix
Received disconnect from: Bye Bye [preauth]
Disconnected from invalid user bitrix
Failed password for root from
Failed password for root from
Failed password for root from
Failed password for root from

But for /etc/init.d/apache2 restart after typing my password i get message AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE

Comment: Let me know if there are any updates.

Comment: What do you mean by "new error"? Error for restart appache attempt?

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140605/discussion-on-answer-by-tu-van-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-ins).

Comment: @AmitBera looks like you forgot the Original Poster does not have enough reputation (min 20 reputation) to join the chat.

Comment: I managed to restart apache (ssh) via Webmin. php.ini.save moved from /etc/php/8.1/cli/ to /etc/php still exists. What i gained are new errors:

Comment: To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-bz2.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini

Comment: - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini

Comment: - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini

Comment: - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you take a screenshot?

Comment: I added screenshots in my first post.

Comment: The screenshot indicates you missing PHP **intl** extension, it is the same as your description in your original post. So, try to remove the semicolon from `;extension=intl` from 2 files: /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini and /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini Then restart your Apache.

Comment: But I already did it before, what i wrote in post from Nov 13 at 18:26.

Comment: Now, after grep -r extension=intl /etc I get /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini:extension=intl
/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini:extension=intl
/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini:extension=intl
/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini:extension=intl
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/intl.ini:extension=intl.so
/etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini:extension=intl
/etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini:extension=intl

Comment: Did you restart Apache? Have you faced this issue locally or on the server?

Comment: Yes, I did it again - I managed to restart apache (ssh) via Webmin, because I had problems doing it by command line /etc/init.d/apache2 restart It is on server. Still same results.

Comment: Maybe some different solutions?

Comment: Are you ok to send me your ssh login credentials? I'll take a look.

Comment: If so, send it to my email: vandinhtuit@gmail.com